# Adding space on top of a background image

Tags: wpf, background-image

I have a simple  grid with buttons and background image. How to add some space on the top of the image?

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <Grid.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="img.png" Strech="None"/>
   <Grid.Background>
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a top Margin to the Grid.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0">
   <Grid.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="img.png" Strech="None"/>
   <Grid.Background>
...
</Grid>
```